# How to separate a-name-and-score-list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

So I have this task where I have to count gamers' scores from a text file and then print the scores. How can I split the name and the score and the count the score for specific name? And the names have to be in alphabetical order.

I have tried this:

```
file = input("Enter the name of the score file: ")
    print("Contestant score:")
    open_file = open(file, "r")
    list = open_file.readlines()
    open_file.close()
    for row in sorted(list):
        row = row.rstrip()
        contestant = row.split(" ")
    if contestant[0] == contestant[0]:
        total = int(contestant[1]) + int(contestant[1])
        print(contestant[0], total)
    print(row)
```

example of the text file:

```
sophia 2

sophia 3

peter 7

matt 10

james 3

peter 5

sophia 5

matt 9
```

And the program should look like this:

```
james 3

matt 19

peter 12

sophia 10
```

And my current output is:

```
sophia 10

sophia 5
```

Comment: What result does your current code supply? Please list your current output *along with* your expected output

Comment: Your indentation is off, or I don't understand what you tried to achieve with that single `if`. Speaking of which, what *are* you trying to achieve with `if contestant[0] == contestant[0]:`? [Edit] your post and explain your algorithm. (And don't use `list` as a variable name. It's kinda [taken](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#list) in Python.)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making a dictionary:

```
# Open Text File
file = input("Enter the name of the score file: ")
print("Contestant score:")
open_file = open(file, "r")
lines = open_file.readlines()

# Convert into one single line for ease
mystr = '\t'.join([line.strip() for line in lines])

# Split it and make dictionary
out = mystr.split()
entries = dict([(x, y) for x, y in zip(out[::2], out[1::2])])

# Unsorted Display
print(entries)

# Sorted Display
print(sorted(entries.items(), key=lambda s: s[0]))
```

Output:

```
[('james', '3'), ('matt', '9'), ('peter', '5'), ('sophia', '5')]
```

You can show/save this dictionary in any form you like like CSV, JSONor keep it like this only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this.

**Code:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

file = input("Enter the name of the score file: ")
results = defaultdict(int)
with open(file, "r") as file:
    # Gather results from each line.
    for line in file:
        name, points = line.split()
        results[name] += int(points)

# Print the results dict.
print("Contestant score:")
for name in sorted(results.keys()):
    print(name, results[name])
```

This works for Python 3.

**Output:**

```
Enter the name of the score file: input.txt
Contestant score:
james 3
matt 19
peter 12
sophia 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to store the total score of each gamer.

```
from collections import defaultdict
scores=defaultdict(int)
with open('score.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            key,val=line.split()
            scores[key]+=int(val)

print(*sorted(scores.items()),sep='\n')
```

---

Output:

```
('james', 3)
('matt', 19)
('peter', 12)
('sophia', 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict
file = input("Enter the name of the score file: ").strip()
results = defaultdict(int)
if(os.path.isfile(file)):
    with open(file) as f:
        for row in sorted([x.strip() for x in list(f) if x]):
            line = row.split()
            if len(line) == 2:
                results[line[0]] += int(line[1])

        print("Contestants scores:")
        for k, v in results.items():
            print(k, v)
else:
    print("File not found", file)
```

---

```
Contestants scores:
james 3
matt 19
peter 12
sophia 10
```

---

[demo](https://trinket.io/python3/fd295d82c6)

Answer (score 0):

I had worked up a solution just using a standard dictionary (not *collections.defaultdict*), so figured I'd post it too.

*Python 3*

**Code:**

```
file = input("Enter the name of the score file: ")
print("Contestant score:")

gamer_dict = {}
with open(file, 'r') as infile:
    for row in infile:
        splits = row.split(" ")
        name = splits[0].strip()
        score = int(splits[1].strip())
        if name not in gamer_dict:
            gamer_dict[name] = score
        else:
            gamer_dict[name] += score

for k,v in sorted(gamer_dict.items()):
    print(k,v)
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the name of the score file: gamers.txt
Contestant score:
james 3
matt 19
peter 12
sophia 10
```